# How to trigger UIButton action programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton

I have several buttons in one class and their actions are separate.
I created the instance of that class in another class, and I have the UIButton array in the 2nd class. I want to call each button's action programmatically. Is there any way to do this in iOS?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

UIButton has a method to invoke the targets/selectors that are linked to a certain control event:

`[button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

2022 Swift syntax:

`someButton.sendActions(for: .primaryActionTriggered)`

Answer (score 21):

For Swift 3.0/4.0/5.0:

```
button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Make sure you are are adding this to an IBOutlet of the button, not a IBAction - the ```.sendAction(for: .touchUpInside)``` part may throw you off.

Comment: UIBarButtonItem does not have a .sendAction member. Is there a way of programmatically calling an action of this object?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call first class's action method as instance method from other classes by passing a UIbutton id

e.g.:
in first class "***ClassA***"

```
- (IBAction)classAbuttonAction1:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)classAbuttonAction2:(id)sender;
```

from another class

```
UIButton *bClassButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];    
ClassA *instance = [[ClassA alloc]init];

[instance classAbuttonAction1:bClassButton];
[instance classAbuttonAction2:bClassButton];
```